# Upgraded rhel apache from 2.2 to 2.4 - authz_core:error - AuthType configured with no corresponding authorization directives - 500 error

Tags: apache, mellon

I upgraded rhel 6 to 7 and it did also the upgrade from apache 2.2 to 2.4 I also have the edgewall trac 1.0.7 version (had to manually deinstall el6 trac10 package and reinstall el7 package). I am using mellond module to authentificate users with saml provider and everythin was working fine with the redhat 6 and apache 2.2
After the upgrade I am getting the following error when I am trying to open the trac web context url: `authz_core:error AH01627: AuthType configured with no corresponding authorization directives`
and I am getting a 500 Error. The Mellon mod was configured using the redhat manual. I am guessing that I need to adapt some apache 2.4 config here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: some code snippets: <Location /trac/test>
        Include conf.d/mellon_conf.include
        Require valid-user
</Location>

WSGIScriptAlias /trac/test /opt/local/conf/trac/sites/test/apache/IRC.wsgi
    <Directory /opt/local/conf/trac/sites/test/apache>
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

Comment: cat mellon_conf.include
        MellonEnable info
        MellonEndpointPath /mellon/
        MellonSPMetadataFile /etc/httpd/saml2/https_xxxxx_mellon_metadata.xml
        MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /etc/httpd/saml2/https_xxxxx_mellon_metadata.key
        MellonSPCertFile /etc/httpd/saml2/https_xxxxx_ellon_metadata.cert
        #MellonIdPMetadataFile /etc/httpd/saml2/idp_metadata.xml
        MellonIdPMetadataFile /etc/httpd/saml2/metadata_xxxxx.xml
        AuthType Mellon
        MellonEnable auth
        MellonUser sub2
        MellonSetEnvNoPrefix REMOTE_USER NAME_ID

Comment: Looks better when I disabled         #AuthType Mellon

Comment: I have an issue now with Tortoise SVN Client when ussing <Location /test>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /opt/local/conf/svn/test

        Include conf.d/mellon_conf.include
        Require user USER1 USER2 USER
        Require all denied
        Satisfy any             then I get in the get  401 381